# Read thai character from text file and write to excel using apache poi

Tags: java, spring, collections, java-8, apache-poi

I am reading the .txt file which contains both english and thai characters and writing those line in excel. But there are some lines where thai characters are printing garbage values in excel. As there will be multiple files, I am reading specific contents adding it to arraylist (will change to treemap later) and writing those arraylist on excel using apache poi.  Below are the sample file content, java code and excel screenshot. Thanks for the help.

Sample File Content:
D000003001100115449620876436327     SIRIYAKON TRI                                          24112024112006100000037343ATM
D000003101100115449620641542361107  นางสุชาวดี กระเทศ                       650283977      24112024112003900000059064CSH

Code:

```
File folder = new File("D:\\Files");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); }
                 else
                 { if (line.startsWith("D"))
                         {
                            String str = line.substring(21,31);
                            subscribernolist.add(str);
                            custnolist.add(line.substring(76,85));
                            customernamelist.add((String) line.substring(36,49));
                         }
 }                   
            }                
            }               
             int currentRow = 0;
                Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Merge Data");
                Row rowheader = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
                Row row;
   rowheader.getCell(0).setCellValue("CUST NO.");
  rowheader.getCell(1).setCellValue("SUBSCRIBER NO.");
rowheader.getCell(2).setCellValue("CUST NAME");       
                    currentRow++;
                
                for (int counter = 0; counter < customernamelist.size(); counter++) {
                     row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(custnolist.get(counter));
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(subscribernolist.get(counter));
                    row.createCell(2).setCellValue(customernamelist.get(counter));
                    currentRow++;
                }
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File ("D:\\Files\\merge.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
                workbook.close();
}
```

Excel writing as below
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your text file is saved as UTF8 not something else? If you print out the text as your program runs, what text does Java think it was?

Comment: No the current encoding when i see in notepad++ is TIS-620

Comment: OK, so what happens if you update your `InputStreamReader` line to configure it for the same encoding that you're using to save the text file in?

Comment: Nothing in excel its still shows garbage characters only.